# Orthogonal Polynomials & Equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, inner-products

**Problem Statement**: Define the inner product of two real functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ in the following way:

$$(f, g) = \int\limits_{-1}^1 f(t)g(t)\;dt$$

Let $P_0(t)=\frac{1}{2}$ and define the other elements $\{P_n(t)\}$ by the condition that $P_n(t)$ is of degree $n$ and $(P_n,P_m)=0$, $m\neq n$, and $(P_n,P_n)=1$. Prove that

$$\left(\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^n (1-t^2)^n, t^m\right)=0,$$

$0\leq m\leq n-1$, and thus express $P_n$ in terms of the expression $\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^n (1-t^2)^n$.

**Attempt**: By the binomial theorem, we know

$$(1-t^2)^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} t^{2(n-k)}$$

and so

$$\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^n (1-t^2)^n=\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^n \sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} t^{2n-2k}$$

$$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}(2n-2k)\cdots (2n-2k-n+1) t^{n-2k}$$

$$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor} (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n}(n-2k)!t^{n-2k}.$$

From here, I know I want to show

$$P_n(t)=\alpha\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^n (1-t^2)^n$$

for some constant $\alpha$, so then we have

$$\left(\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^n (1-t^2)^n, t^m\right)=\alpha(P_n,t^m)=0$$

as $P_n$ is orthogonal to $t^m$ by construction. However, I am not sure how to construct the sequence $P_n$ - I tried explicitly, but I don't see the pattern. Any help is appreciated with establishing the correspondence!

**Source**: "Introduction to Matrix Analysis" by Richard Bellman. FYI, I am working through all the problems in the book for enjoyment on break, not coursework.

Comment: Notice that $\alpha$ may still depend on $n$ and that you have not used the fact that you want $(P_n,P_n)=1$.

Comment: $\alpha$ just cannot be in terms of $t$ I think. As for the latter fact, you think it would be helpful to consider looking at $\alpha^2\int\limits_{-1}^1 \left(\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^n (1-t^2)\right)^2\;dt=\alpha^2\int\limits_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^{2n} (1-t^2)\;dt=1$?

Comment: If I try that, I get $\alpha = \pm \sqrt{\frac{(-1)^n}{2(2n)!}}$, but I'm still not sure if I can show this must be $P_n$ - it'd then be to show this is orthogonal to $P_i$, $i\leq n-1$ I guess.

Comment: Use linearity of the integral to kill the inner product.

Comment: I think I made some algebra error - you're suggesting to use my expression for the $n$th derivative in terms of the sum inside the integral and pull that sum outside, but on the inside of the integral, I have $1-(-1)^{n-2k+m+1}$ which I wish necessarily vanished, but I don't think it does

Comment: No, I am suggesting that you use that $P_n=\sum _{0\leq i\leq n} \beta _i t^i$ and the coefficients really do not matter if you already showed that $(P_n,t^m)=0$.